# how to create a method with a selector parameter

Tags: objective-c, parameter-passing, selector

Hi I'm trying to make an objective-C method that has a selector as parameter. But I keep receiving the "unrecognized selector sent to instance " error message. I'm doing the following:

this is the method with the selector parameter:

```
-(void)createURL: (SEL) selector{ 
dispatch_sync(kBgQueue,^{
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: wcfURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(selector)
                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];


});
}
```

this is the method i want to be the selector:

```
-(void)fetchedUserType:(NSData *)responseData{

NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];

userType = [json objectForKey:@"getUserTypeResult"];
}
```

and this is where I'm calling my method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://10.211.55.3:1234/Service1.svc/getUserType/%@", userEmail];
wcfURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:url];
SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(@"fetchedUserType:");
[self createURL:sel];
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT 1:

**Your error is here:**

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(selector)
 ----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`selector` is already a selector, and your are putting it in `@selector(`) again.

It should be

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:selector withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
```

---

Edit 0:

Your codes are correct. And you get the error only **when your SEL method in not found in the current class**.

As in the code below, if I change the method name `sum` to `add` this will throw the same error.

```
-(void)sum{
    NSLog(@"sum");
}

-(void) createURL: (SEL) selector{
    [self performSelector:selector];
}

- (IBAction)total:(id)sender {
    SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(@"sum");
    [self createURL:sel];
}
```

---

Also, you need to meet the **method signature** as well. If your method takes one argument, You need to send exactly one.

```
-(void)sum:(id)integer{
    NSLog(@"sum:%ld",[integer integerValue]);
}

-(void) createURL: (SEL) selector{
    //NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: nil];
    //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(selector) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

    [self performSelector:selector withObject:@(12)];
}

- (IBAction)total:(id)sender {
    NSInteger total=0;

    for (id element in self.arrayController.arrangedObjects) {
        total += [element firstNumber]*[element secondNumber];
    }
    [self.label setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",total]];


    SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(@"sum:");
    [self createURL:sel];

}
```

Comment: but it is all in the same class and I'm receiving the error message

Comment: your selector name is `nameOFmyMethodSelector:` so r u sure you passing a parameter too?

Comment: In other words, including a colon at the end means you are also passing a parameter.  There is a difference between `nameOFmyMethodSelector:` and `nameOFmyMethodSelector`

Comment: the NSData i declared inside createURL is the parameter for nameOFmyMethodSelector: so I believe everything it's ok with that

Comment: oohh I see, thank you very much, I've been trying to fix it for hours!!

Comment: my pleasure. And from next time, always show your full code ;)